# Mule flow designer Database connection

Tags: mule

I'm trying the new mule flow designer and when I try to test my database connection, it throws an error "Could not obtain connection from data source". My mysql is running and am able to connect to it from other tools.

I could not find any more information on the error.

I'm using the mySQL JDBC driver 5.1.43 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Can someone please help here

thanks

Comment: Check with the correct URL Syntax

Comment: I am using the web based flow deisgner and there is not place where I can find the URL syntax. The configauration is asking me for the host, port,database, username and password. I have given all of these.